# How to use Azure Key Vault's Secret for Docker Login

Tags: azure, docker, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I have a Azure Container Registry and Azure Key Vault with Secret. Now I want to perform Docker login using that secret.

I am new to ACR and Docker. So don't have any idea how to consume secret for docker login.

Comment: Could you please describe your case more clearly, what is your architecture, where are you going to run docker container, who will consume Azure Key Vault with Secret, etc?

Comment: you can enable managed identities and configure task to read credentials stored in an Azure key vault. this link will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-authentication-key-vault

Comment: Please refer this as well : https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/docker-compose-azure-key-vault-passing-secrets-to-a-container-on-startup